# How to check whether value in QTable widget changed

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator

HI,

I have some data there in my tablewidget and it is editable. My intention is to take data from   edited row and column. IS it possible. Is it possible to check the edited row and column.
Any specific signal is there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course,

```
void QTableWidget::itemChanged ( QTableWidgetItem * item )   [signal]
```

This signal is emitted whenever the data of item has changed.

Add connect like this:

```
connect(tableWidget,
    SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *)), this, SLOT(on_any_itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem *)));
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the row and column position of changed (row,column)

Comment: How to get the row and column position of changed data

Comment: @sijith Yes, it's possible. When on_any_itemChanged() emited, use pointer item to get row/column, like  *qDebug() << item->row();*

Comment: Hye @mosg I have QComboBox in every row of QTableWidget cell. I want to get row number when user change value in particular QComboBox.